# Google App Engine: Snapshot Database?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Hey guys, I want to write some code for our staging server that "snapshots" the GAE database by walking through each Model in the db and serializing/unserializing it in a recoverable way.

This doesn't have to be thread-safe, it's purely for things like demos, and we'd love for it to run on the high replication DB.

there will be *very* little data in the DB, just enough to run a demo, so it can be a really dirty hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason why you can't just use the standard [bulkloader](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html)? You can just tell it to download all entities of all kinds, so you don't have to know their names a priori:

```
 appcfg.py download_data --application=<app-id> --url=http://<appname>.appspot.com/[remote_api_path] --filename=<data-filename>
```

And to upload you can do the reverse:

```
appcfg.py upload_data --application=<app-id> --kind=<kind> --filename=<data-filename> <app-directory>
```

I'm not entirely sure if it will give you a snapshot in time (e.g., if it blocks all new writes until it's done) and I would venture to say 'no', but if you really need a true snapshot in time you could just disable writes in your app, grab the data, and re-enable it (although how to do that can be a bit kloogy).

Comment: Seems like this would work for the asker.  If it's only specific models that need to be backed up this script could be modified to do it: https://gist.github.com/882011

Comment: 2013 update: this solution works only for Master-Slave datastore.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a "Write my code for me" question...

To give you a short answer, feel free to run a for loop through your models (since you say there isn't a lot of data stored) and save everything as, for example, a json string or something you could easily restore.

Comment: I can't do a Model.all() (it returns no results), so I'd have to list out each model that I wanted to save by hand, right?

Comment: Actually that's very good question. My answer completely ignore this aspect because I don't know myself the answer, assuming your Models are hard coded and, therefore, available for you to name manually in your script.